# How can I configure custom service endpoints for FIPS compliance using Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, fips

In order to meet FedRAMP compliance, we need to make all communication FIPS compliant.

In Terraform there is an option to define [custom endpoints](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/custom-service-endpoints), which will make API calls to AWS using the [FIPS endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/fips/) in our use case.

Can I configure custom service endpoints for FIPS compliance using Serverless Framework? If so, how?

Comment: I haven't done work with GovCloud but I know for local services like Localstack to work with SF, [they patch the client libraries](https://github.com/localstack/serverless-localstack/blob/master/src/index.js#L524) within their own plugin. There may be a plugin for FIPS but I think the answer is - there's no built-in way.

Comment: I might be completely wrong however, a few regulars here do tons in GovCloud so hopefully they can confirm.